# Bootstrap 3 - Change figcaption color inside a tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.tab-img-size {
    width: 130px;
    height: auto;
}

.tab-img-caption-color a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav active col-md-3"><a href="#water1" data-toggle="tab"><figure><img src="http://water1.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-3_05.png" class="tab-img-size center-block"><figcaption class="text-center"><h3 class="tab-img-caption-color">Water 1</h3></figcaption></figure></a></li>
                <li class="nav col-md-3"><a href="#water2" data-toggle="tab"><figure><img src="http://water1.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-3_05.png" class="tab-img-size center-block"><figcaption class="text-center"><h3>Water 2</h3></figcaption></figure></a></li>
                <li class="nav col-md-3"><a href="#water3" data-toggle="tab"><figure><img src="http://water1.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo-3_05.png" class="tab-img-size center-block"><figcaption class="text-center"><h3>Water 3</h3></figcaption></figure></a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="water1">Content inside tab Water 1</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="water2">Content inside tab Water 2</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="water3">Content inside tab Water 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to change the color of the text inside `<figcaption>` (e.g. "Water 1") when the tab is active, inactive, and hover. Currently the color is Black, Blue, and Dark Blue respectively.

I added `.tab-img-caption-color` to change the inactive color and tried to use it on `<h3>` (i also tried every element inside `<a>`) but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve . As the color of text water1 2 3 are changing on tab change?

Comment: @sahildhir change the color of the text (when active, hover, or inactive) into what I want instead of the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have given red color on hover and active state. You can change color as you want.

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pssw66t6/3/)**

```
ul.nav-tabs li:hover h3, .nav-tabs li.active h3{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Sweet. This is what I'm looking for, Thank you. But isn't `:hover` supposed to be `<a>`'s?

Comment: You can, Actually bootstrap plugin css is giving more priority than fiddle css. Now just put `color:red !important;`. https://jsfiddle.net/pssw66t6/4/ in this demo works perfect. I just didn't want to use `!important` that's why.